# How to create an ARRAY in PHP to display correct format?

Tags: php, arrays

I am in a unique fix. It is easy but for the love of god I havent able to figure it out.

**Code**

```
// Loop through results
for($k=0;$k<count($orderNumber);$k++) {
    // Add a new array for each iteration
    $div[] = array (
        $orderNumber[$k]=>array(
            "customerOrderId"=>$orderNumber[$k],
            "status"=>$orderStatus[$k],
            "readyTime"=>$orderShipDate[$k]
        ));
}
```

**Returns**

```
[
  {}
  {}
  {}
]
```

I although need the API to return in the following format.

```
"orders" : {
  {}
  {}
  {}
}
```

Can someone guide me in the correct direction?

Comment: Add a key named `orders`, like  `$div['orders'] = array (...)`. And you can't have an object of objects like you want, you will have `"orders": [ {}, {}, {} ]` as final result.

Comment: Do you need to include the order numbers as keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all of you who helped me. This is what I ended up with and works perfectly as I need.

```
for($k=0;$k<count($orderNumber);$k++) {
        // Add a new array for each iteration
        $div['orders'][$orderNumber[$k]] = array (
            "customerOrderId"=>$orderNumber[$k],
            "status"=>$orderStatus[$k],
            "readyTime"=>$orderShipDate[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$orderNumber   = ['10', '23'];
$orderStatus   = ['pending', 'shipped'];
$orderShipDate = ['2023', '2019'];

for($k=0;$k<count($orderNumber);$k++) {
    $div['orders'][$orderNumber[$k]] = array (
            "customerOrderId"=>$orderNumber[$k],
            "status"=>$orderStatus[$k],
            "readyTime"=>$orderShipDate[$k]
    );
}

echo json_encode($div, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "orders": {
        "10": {
            "customerOrderId": "10",
            "status": "pending",
            "readyTime": "2023"
        },
        "23": {
            "customerOrderId": "23",
            "status": "shipped",
            "readyTime": "2019"
        }
    }
}
```

If you drop the order keying for a sequential append you'll get a list output:

```
$div['orders'][] = array (
```

Output (with the line above swapped in):

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "customerOrderId": "10",
            "status": "pending",
            "readyTime": "2023"
        },
        {
            "customerOrderId": "23",
            "status": "shipped",
            "readyTime": "2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was almost close.